# Deserializing custom JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I am attempting to deserilize some custom JSON into a Dictionary, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to approach it. I've done it before having a Model class, but in this case, I need to do it in a specific way.

Here's what the Json looks like:

```
 {
     Values:
        {
          "Value1":"XXX",
          "value2" :
                 {
                       "SubValue1":"YX",
                       "SubValue2":"AB"
                 }
       }
}
```

The goal here would be to create a Dictionary<string,string> and populate it, so that:

```
    Key          Value
    Value1       XXX
    Value2       {
                   "SubValue1":"YX",
                   "SubValue2":"AB"
                 }
```

Is there a quick way to get this deserilized like that? Any tips or hints on how to get this done easily?

Comment: How do you plan on putting that data in a `Dictionary<string,string>`? Maybe a `Dictionary<string,object>`? Either way, I believe you'll need to handle the deserialization (custom converter)...

Comment: That should deserialize almost directly with Newtonsoft and using `[I]Dictionary<string,X>` as the target (either with the Value mapped to an object or string, depending on desired results as it is unclear from the question). What was the result when attempting to do so? Or is the serialize limited to `Text.Json`?

Comment: @zaggler, for Value2, couldn't the value simply be as the JSON block as string?

Comment: @Sandro yes it could, but you would then need to deserialize that to get what you need out of it... It depends on how you want to handle that data.

Comment: @zaggler - That's understandable. I would want Value2 to be in a JSON block in dictionary as string. Later I would deserlize the SubValues

Comment: Newtonsoft's JObject is IDictionary, but also gives the possibility to get deeper without further deserialization.

Comment: @Nikolaus thanks. I'll give it a google, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, I converterted your json to Dictionary<string,string>

```
var json = "{\"Values\":{\"Value1\":\"XXX\",\"value2\":{\"SubValue1\":\"YX\",\"SubValue2\":\"AB\"}}}";
var jsonDeserialized =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

Dictionary<string,string>  dict = jsonDeserialized.Values.ToDictionary(i => i.Key, j => j.Value.ToString());

dict["value2"] = dict["value2"].Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
```

output

```
{
  "Value1": "XXX",
  "value2": "{\"SubValue1\":\"YX\",\"SubValue2\":\"AB\"}"
}
```

how to use

```
string value1 = dict["Value1"];
Value value2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Value>(dict["value2"]);
Values values = new Values { Value1=value1, Value2=value2 };
```

value1

```
XXX
```

value2

```
{
"SubValue1":"YX",
"SubValue2":"AB"
}
```

classes

```
public class Values
{
    public string Value1 {get; set;}
    public Value Value2 {get; set;}
}
public class Value
{
    public string SubValue1 { get; set; }
    public string SubValue2 { get; set; }
}
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, Object> Values { get; set; }
}
```